# Crop image in HTML5

Tags: javascript, css, image, canvas

I am using below given fiddle to apply zoom in and zoom out on my canvas image, but when i zoom out my image it shows multiple images slices. This problem does not show in fiddle possibly because its image background is white.
If any one knows how to solve this problem kindly give an idea about it. Thanks

Comment: This is the fiddle i am using  http://jsfiddle.net/AbdiasSoftware/nWyDE/20/#

Comment: I tried in Chrome, works as expected

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you forget to clear your canvas between each `draw`:

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/canvas_clearrect.asp

Comment: I'm applying clear canvas function also, but its not working.

Answer (score 0):

```
context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
```

Note that for clearRect you need to either have an untransformed context, or keep track of your actual boundaries.

Comment: I already have use this code mate but my problem is related to cropping of image.